# since java creates a new object when new keyword is used, and every object has unique hashcode, then why here it is giving same hashcode output?

Tags: java, string, object, hashcode

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1="shrey";
        String str2="shrey";
        String str3=new String("shrey");
        System.out.println(str1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(str2.hashCode());
        System.out.println(str3.hashCode());
    }
}
```

output = same hashcode of all str1, str2, str3

Java uses string pool. I know it. `str1` and `str2` are created using string literal so they should refer to same object and hence will generate the same hashcode but, `str3` is created using `new` keyword, so I was expecting hashcode of `str3` to be different but it came out to be same. Why?

Comment: `*[...] every object has unique hashcode*` - That is not true. It is not possible to map infinite number of possible objects to a finite set of hashcodes. Moreover, *equal* objects should have the same hashcode. Here, the hashcode of a string is based on the individual characters.

Comment: Nowhere in the specification of the `Object::hashCode` method does it say that hashcodes are unique.

Comment: `hashCode` has a relationship with `equals` in that any two objects which are `equal` should also have the same `hashCode` - [quick google for more details](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+hashcode+equals&rlz=1C5GCEM_enAU1020AU1020&oq=java+hashcode+equals&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCDY3ODFqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 3):

Your question is based on false assumptions:

> Since java creates a new object when new keyword is used,

Correct

> ... and every object has unique hashcode,

Incorrect!  Nothing in any of the Java specifications states that hashcodes are unique.  In fact, the closest it comes to that is this line from the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) for `Object`.

> *"Implementation Requirements:  As far as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by class `Object` returns distinct integers for distinct objects."*

That says try to make them distinct if you can ... but it does not guarantee that they will be distinct.  Indeed, it is provably impossible to guarantee that in the context of Java.

> ... then why here it is giving same hashcode output?

That is nothing to do with `Object::hashCode`.  You code is actually calling the `String::hashCode`, and that is specified to return a value that is independent of the string's identity.  The `String` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) states:

> *"Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a `String` object is computed as*
>
> ```
> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> ```
>
> *using `int` arithmetic, where `s[i]` is the `i`th character of the string, `n` is the length of the string, and `^` indicates exponentiation."*

Your strings all have the same length and the same characters, so that means that `String::hashCode` will give the same result.

We can also infer that this should be the case from the properties of `hashCode` and `equals` as set out in the `Object` javadocs.  In concise terms:

```
s1.equals(s2) == true  implies  s1.hashCode() == s2.hashCode()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion that "every object has a unique hashcode" is incorrect.  Rather, the rule is that equal objects must have the same hash code.  Unequal objects may or may not have different hash codes (though for performance reasons it is important most unequal objects do).

Per the contract of [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), objects which are equal according to [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) must have equal hash codes:

> If two objects are equal according to the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Per the `String` [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), two `String` values are considered equal according to `equals` when they represent the same sequence of characters:

> The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

`"shrey"` and `new String("shrey")` represent the same sequence of characters (namely, `{'s', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'y'}`).  Therefore, they are equal according to `equals` and must  have the same hash code.

Finally, to add a little more context, the Javadocs for `hashCode` explain that two unequal objects may have the same hash code, though doing so comes with performance consequences:

> It is *not* required that if two objects are unequal according to the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

The Java programming language `equals` and `hashCode` contract states that two equal objects according to `equals(Object object)` method must have equal hash codes, while two objects with equal hash codes could be different  from one to another.

There are details about the `hashCode` method contract in Java documentation of `Object` class of the Java programming language version of your preference.

Answer (score 0):

`#hashcode` will give you the same hash value for all objects that are the same in terms of their literal value. So any string with the value "eclips3", no matter how it is constructed, and whether or not `#intern` is applied, will have the same hashcode.

What is more suited for your purposes is `System.identityHashCode(stringObj)`, which is basically the original implementation of `#hashcode` by Object before it gets overridden. As a result, we can use this method to distinguish references [stored in separate memory locations] even when they have the same literal value.

Here a basic demo to help you get a better idea:

```
        String s1 = "eclips3";
        String s2 = new String("eclips3");
        String s3 = new String("eclips3");
        String s4 = s2.intern();
        String s5 = new String("eclips3").intern();

        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s1));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s2));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s3));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s4));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s5));
        
        System.out.println("s1 == s2? " + String.valueOf(s1==s2));
        System.out.println("s1 == s3? " + String.valueOf(s1==s3));
        System.out.println("s1 == s4? " + String.valueOf(s1==s4));
        System.out.println("s1 == s5? " + String.valueOf(s1==s5));
        System.out.println("s2 == s3? " + String.valueOf(s2==s3));
        System.out.println("s2 == s4? " + String.valueOf(s2==s4));
        System.out.println("s2 == s5? " + String.valueOf(s2==s5));
        System.out.println("s3 == s4? " + String.valueOf(s3==s4));
        System.out.println("s3 == s5? " + String.valueOf(s3==s5));
        System.out.println("s4 == s5? " + String.valueOf(s4==s5));
```

Results on my system:

```
95980430
1478835287
12006451
95980430
95980430
s1 == s2? false
s1 == s3? false
s1 == s4? true
s1 == s5? true
s2 == s3? false
s2 == s4? false
s2 == s5? false
s3 == s4? false
s3 == s5? false
s4 == s5? true
```